# How to fire an event when a DialogBox got hided in GWT?

Tags: gwt, dialog, gwtp

I want to call a method whenever my `DialogBox` is hidden. It doesn't matter how it is hidden, it could be someone click close button or it can be hidden by itself. When that happen the system will call a method.

Look at this code.

```java
public class WishListDialogBox extends DialogBox {
    @UiField Button closeButton;
    public WishListDialogBox() {
        setHTML("Wish List");
        setWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
        closeButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

                hide();
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        super.hide();
        //call some action here;
    }
}
```

The above code only work when I click CloseButton, but when the `DialogBox` was hidden by itself, nothing happened.

There is no `onHide` event in `DialogBox`.

In traditional Java, there is addWindowListener to handle his very easily, but that is missing in GWT `DialogBox`.

So, How to fire an event when a `DialogBox` is hidden in `GWT`?

Answer (score 6):

Finally I found a solution

```java
this.addCloseHandler(new CloseHandler(){
    @Override
    public void onClose(CloseEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //do some action here
    }
});
```